# Find $x$, given: $x^2 + \frac{9x^2}{(x+3)^2} = 16$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

Here's an equation:

$$x^2 + \frac{9x^2}{(x+3)^2} = 16$$

First, I subtracted 16 from both sides and factored $x^2$ so I would get a quadratic equation, but with no success. Also, I can see that the equation can be rewritten as:

$$(x+4)(x-4) + \left(\frac{3x}{x+3}\right)^2 = 0$$
But I can't see how can I use that information.

What should I do?

Comment: Multiply everything by $(x+3)^2$ to get rid of the fraction. Bring everything to one side, so that now you have a quartic polynomial. You can then factorize it, in this case into two quadratic factors.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can rewrite it as:
\begin{align*}
\left(\frac{x}{4}\right)^2 + \left(\frac{3x}{4(x+3)}\right)^2 & = 1.
\end{align*}
Let $\frac{x}{4}=\cos A$, then $\frac{3x}{4(x+3)}=\sin A$. Using $x=4 \cos A$ in the expression for $\sin A$, we get
\begin{align*}
12 (\cos A -\sin A) & = 8 \sin 2A\\
9(\cos A -\sin A)^2 & = 4 \sin ^22A\\
9(1-\sin 2A)&=4 \sin^2 2A.
\end{align*}
Now you have a quadratic in $\sin 2A$. Can you proceed from here?

**Comment: (added)**
This quadratic gives $\sin2A= -3$ or $\sin 2A=\frac{3}{4}$. The former cannot happen (for real values of $x$). The latter upon substituting back in terms of $x$ gives two real solutions $x=1\pm \sqrt{7}$.

Comment: Thanks, a great way to solve this problem. It took me some time to figure out exactly why your way of solving works and how did you get there, and before you added a comment I had all figured out and solved! I appreciate your help.

Comment: @Lanet Thanks!! glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

Multiply by $(x+3)^2$,

$$x^2(x+3)^2+9x^2=16(x+3)^2$$

or

$$x^4+6x^3+2x^2-96x-144=0.$$

Using a solver, the roots are irrational, but there is a rational factorization in two quadratic polynomials.

Comment: Is that last step factorization obvious? Doesn't look that way to me.

Comment: @Ennar: did I say it was ? This is why I tagged as a hint.

Comment: You didn't, I asked an honest question, not to poke at your answer.

Comment: @Ennar: I confirm that it is not obvious.

Answer (score 0):

$$(x+4)(x-4) + \left(\frac{3x}{x+3}\right)^2 = 0$$

multiply by $(x+3)^2$

$$(x+4)(x-4)(x+3)^2 + 9x^2 = 0$$
$$x^4+6x^3+2x^2-96x-144=0$$

$$(x^2-2x-6)(x^2+8x+24)=0$$

real solutions :  $x=1\pm \sqrt{7}$

complex solutions : $x=-4\pm\iota 2\sqrt{2}$

Comment: Is that last step factorization obvious? Doesn't look that way to me.

Comment: no, it is not obvious

Comment: Then it's the same as Yves Daoust's answer.

Comment: then a very obvious way is hit and trial find one root try to factorize it also can't two answers be same because of we published our answers almost at the same time